# How to use regexp in bash script

Tags: regex, bash

```
# Checking if we dealing with 1050 or 1050 Ti
function gpu_check() {
  test="GPU 0: GeForce GTX 1050 (UUID: GPU-97acce0b-4304-01e9-ef9d-bc3230cae912)"
  echo "testing $test"
  if [[ $test =~ "\sGTX\s1050\s" ]]; then
    echo "foud 1050"
  else
    echo "no 1050's here"
  fi
}
```

i'm trying to use regex but all possible variants i can imagine, like double \, adding * and .*, using "$test" and many more, giving me not what i'm expecting.

> testing GPU 0: GeForce GTX 1050 (UUID: GPU-97acce0b-4304-01e9-ef9d-bc3230cae912)
>
> no 1050's here

How do i make it work?

Comment: `\s` is a PCRE-ism. It's not available in BRE or ERE regex syntaxes.

Comment: What should i use insted?

Comment: @medik, wrong -- bash does have regex syntax. And please, **please** don't ever advise folks to use the ABS as a reference -- it's the W3Schools of shell scripting, full of bad-practice examples and outdated content.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re='[[:space:]]GTX[[:space:]]1050[[:space:]]'
[[ $test =~ $re ]]
```

...will do the trick.

- `\s` is PCRE syntax. `=~` only guarantees POSIX ERE syntax, so PCRE extensions aren't available. `[[:space:]]` is the POSIX-compliant equivalent.
- You can't quote the regex without making it literal. That is to say -- it **must** be `=~ $re` and not `=~ "$re"` if you want the value in `re` to be treated as a regular expression rather than an exact string to search for.

Quoting from the documentation on [the bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression#regular_expression_matching):

> Using the operator =~, the left hand side operand is matched against the extended regular expression (ERE) on the right hand side.
>
> This is consistent with matching against patterns: **Every quoted part of the regular expression is taken literally, even if it contains regular expression special characters.**
>
> Best practice is to put the regular expression to match against into a variable. This is to avoid shell parsing errors on otherwise valid regular expressions.

Comment: Edit the typo please and i'll accept your answer. re=' bla "